# POIXMLProperties read Property Sets

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, apache-poi, apache-tika

I am trying to read a specific property using Apache POI, my aim is to change its value and save the file in a different location. The issue is that the property in question is not a core, custom or extended one...Its format as shown by Apache Tika is:

```xml
<meta name="meta:just-a-name" content="165" />
```

I have read that with the HPSF API it was possible to read every kind of property in Property Sets, but since my file is a newer version, I cannot use it.

With a custom property I was able to do:

```java
POIXMLProperties properties = document.getProperties();
CTProperty aProperty = properties.getCustomProperties().getProperty("Custom_prop");
aProperty.setI4(12);
properties.commit();
document.write(out);
```

Do you know how I can do the same thing with the non-standard property?

Comment: The Apache Tika code that uses Apache POI to extract the custom properties is https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-parsers/tika-parsers-standard/tika-parsers-standard-modules/tika-parser-microsoft-module/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/ooxml/MetadataExtractor.java#L160 - your code looks pretty close, what isn't working?